# CDI will not work with implicit @Dependent scope, unsatisfied injection point compile time error

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, cdi, managed-bean, glassfish-4.1

The container is Glassfish 4.1

I am having a very weird issue with CDI right now. If I don't annotate my `NumberGenerator` services `@Dependent`, then I keep getting unsatisfied injection point error when I run the app. But if I explicitly annotate my `NumberGenerator` implementations, then everything will work. In one word, if I want dependency injection with the `@Dependent` which is the default scope, I must specify it explicitly.

```
 public interface NumberGenerator {
    String generateNumber();  
 }
```

The first implementation of `NumberGenerator`

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ThirteenDigits
@Dependent
public class IsbnGenerator implements NumberGenerator {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    public String generateNumber() {
        String isbn = "13-84356-" + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Generated ISBN : {0}", isbn);
        return isbn;
    }

}
```

The second implementation of `NumberGenerator`

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@EightDigits
@Dependent
public class IssnGenerator implements NumberGenerator {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    public String generateNumber() {
        String issn = "8-" + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());
        logger.info("Generated ISSN : " + issn);
        return issn;
    }

}
```

This is where the `NumberGenerator` will be injected

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;


@Dependent
public class BookService {

    @Inject 
    @EightDigits
    private NumberGenerator numberGenerator;

    public Book createBook(String title, float price, String description) {
        Book book = new Book(title, price, description);
        book.setNumber(numberGenerator.generateNumber());
        return book;
    }

}
```

Finally, the `BookService` is injected into this JSF managed bean to create a `Book` instance.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@Dependent /* if I leave this out, then this bean will not display 
              the book instance properties on the JSF page, I just see
              a blank screen, but when I add this @Dependent annotation
              the JSF page displays the dummy content below.
           */
public class MyBean {

    @Inject
    private BookService bookService;

    public Book getBook() {
    return bookService.createBook("Dummy Title", 21.05f, "Dummy Description");
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have to use `@Dependent` for the default scope every time I want DI. Right now, I am injecting the `IssnGenerator` with the qualifier `@EightDigits` into the `BookService` class, and if I remove the `@Dependent` from the `IssnGenerator`, I receive this compile error.

```
 Unsatisfied dependencies for type NumberGenerator with qualifiers @EightDigits at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @EightDigits private BookService.numberGenerator
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: No one wants to help at all? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not specify a `META-INF/beans.xml` file, which seems to be your case, you got an *implicit bean archive* ([see CDI-1.1 §12.1](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive)).

In an *implicit bean archive*, only beans with a *bean defining annotation* will be discovered by the CDI engine.

Any scope is a *bean defining annotation* ([see CDI-1.1 §2.5](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations)). That's why if you add a scope, like `@Dependent`, you bean gets discovered by CDI and you don't have the unsatisfied dependency error.

The fact that `@Dependent` is the default scope is not relevant here because without the any scope your beans is simply not discovered.

If you add a `META-INF/beans.xml` file with the `bean-discovery-mode` set to `all`, then you got an *explicit bean archive*, this means that all beans in your archive will be discovered and will have the `@Dependent` scope by default.